# Get the value of textbox under datalist itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net

Here is my problem 
A datalist and item template created at run time in asp.net when change value of textbox under datalist item template and page postback due to textchanged event **but the datalist drop and datalist created again in pageload and textbox value drop.**

```
void CreateDL(Control container)
    {
        var st = settings.CustomPossition();
        foreach (var item in settings.CustomPossition())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Possition");
            dt.Columns.Add("Production");
            dt.Columns.Add("dpo");
            dt.Columns.Add("WorkDay");
            DataRow dr;
            foreach (var users in item.Users)
            {

                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Name"] = users.Name;
                dr["Possition"] = users.Position.Name;
                dr["Production"] = users.DailyGoalAmount * users.WorkDays;
                dr["dpo"] = users.DailyGoalAmount;
                dr["WorkDay"] = users.WorkDays;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                dt.AcceptChanges();

            }
            DataList dataList = new DataList();      
         //   dataList.ItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("Commnets.ascx");
            container.Controls.Add(dataList);

            dataList.DataSource = dt;
            dataList.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

how i can access value of textbox.

Comment: Put your DATA LIST creation code in IsPostBack condition, and show us what you had done.
Without any code how can we imagine what you had made mistake.?

Comment: ok. m putting the code. but in ISPOSTBACK the datalist drop after page postback.

Comment: I think it would be better if you add relevant code to your post. So that we can help you in better way.

Comment: please give me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Page.IsPostBack:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
//Your code
}
else
{
//Other code
}
```